# How to add DOM objects in each in iteration jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have just learned from best practice that is is a lot better to do something like this

```
var check_icon = $('<i />', {class: 'check icon'});
```

instead of this

```
var check_icon = '<i class="check icon"></i>
```

What I need to do is to create a list of these and I am therefore using each to my data and what to use the check_icon in front of each. Something like this:

```
var all = '';
$.each(json, function(id, val) {
    all += checkicon + val;
});
$('#output').html(all);
```

My problem is that it does not work. Instead of giving me the HTML code it returns:

```
[object Object]Carl[object Object]John
```

I know I can append the data in the `$.each` but this is quite CPU intensive and goes against best practices.

I have tried several ways of getting it to work (converting to HTML/string in different ways, but nothing works. I either get `[object Object]` or null)

Comment: `checkicon.html() + val;` do the job?

Comment: ["conf","logfiles","tmp","www"] but it is the same if I dont include the val. Those are the only thing that gets displayed correct.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that you are confusing jQuery objects with HTML strings. It is a little hard to tell what you are trying to do, but here is what I think might work for you.

```
var output = $("#output");
$.each(json, function(id, val) {
    var check_icon = $("<i>").addClass("check icon");
    check_icon.html(val);
    output.append(check_icon);
});
```

Comment: what is the use of id and val in loop

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote the function which can be use to make all kind of DOM element dynamically

```
function makeElement(element, options) {
    var $element = document.createElement(element);
    $.each(options, function (key, value) {
            $element.setAttribute(key, value);

    });
    return $element;
}
```

and you can invoke it as whenever you required.

```
var checkIcon = makeElement('i', {class: 'check icon'});
$('parent-container').appendChild(checkIcon);
```